# Where Am I? In Mexico City (Level One)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Well, this is a "Where am I?" puzzle set around Mexico City Metro. Remember that three is important. You have only the picture.

[image: Puzzling, right?]

This is short, and I think it's easy. Hope you like it!

Comment: Can you explain what a "Where am I" puzzle is?

Comment: Basically locate the location. (Sorry for the tongue-twister.)

Comment: So each of the colours might represent a train line on the mexico city metro network.  The size of each colour block might indicate how far on that train line to travel. A change in colour might indicate to change train lines. Anyway that's my train of thought - hahaha.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I at Tacubaya station? It seems to be the intersection of the three colors provided.